# Sets that are elements or not elements of themselves

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Russell's Paradox involves a test whether a set x is an element of itself.

But from a naive set theory perspective, sets have a hiearchy, per definitionem a set cannot be an element of itself. This seems to be a formalisation problem.

What axioms are meant to preclude this?

Comment: In ZF, the Axiom of Foundation rules this out. In Morse-Kelley  you can construct R but then it's easy to prove that R is not a set.

Comment: The [axiom of regularity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity). If $x\in x$ then $\{x\}$ has no $\in$-minimal element.

Comment: Yes, see [History of Type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_type_theory): Gödel (1944): "By the theory of simple types I mean the doctrine which says that the objects of thought (or, in another interpretation, the symbolic expressions) are divided into types, namely: individuals, properties of individuals, relations between individuals, properties of such relations, etc."

Comment: Note though that what prevents Russell's construction from going   through in ZF is not the axiom of regularity / foundation. It's the _absence_ of unrestricted comprehension.

Comment: In NF and related systems the key point is that comprehension formulas are required to be stratified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The true issue is not self-membership

The real problem is not with $R\notin R$ itself.  In most set theories this is the usual case, and the intention is that $R\notin R$ for *all* $R$. Instead, the real problem is with a *universal set*, which is a set $V$ that contains all sets.

[Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) shows that for any set $S$, there is another set, $$\mathscr P(S)= \{x \mid x\subseteq S\},$$ which is **strictly larger** than $S$.   The proof is: Let $f$ be any map from  $S$  to $ \mathscr P(S)$. Construct the set $R$ of all $x$ for which $x\notin f(x)$.  Then there is no $r$ for which $f(r) = R$, therefore there are elements of $\mathscr P(S)$ which are not in the range of $f$.  Since this is true for *any* $f$, $ \mathscr P(S)$ is bigger than $S$.

If there were a universal set $V$, this argument would  lead us to  [Cantor's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_paradox):  According to Cantor's theorem, $\mathscr P(V)$ is strictly larger than $V$ itself.  But $V$ is the set of all sets, and $\mathscr P(V)$ is a set of *some* sets, so $V$  must be at least as large as $\mathscr P(V)$.

($V$ has the property that $x\in V$ whenever $x\subseteq V$, so applying the proof of Cantor's theorem to $V$ produces exactly the Russell set $\{R\in V\mid R\notin R\}$.)

So **universal sets are impossible**. Different theories have different ways of ruling out universal sets.

### ZF

Most (not all) systems of set theory have your notion of a hierarchy built in. The most common, [Zermelo-Fraenkel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (ZF), was explicitly created with this idea in mind, although its encoding in the the axioms is not explicit.  The closest thing ZF has is the so-called [**axiom of regularity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), also called the **axiom of foundation**.

#### Regularity

For technical reasons the axiom is expressed in a rather opaque way.  It says that every nonempty set $S$ must contain an element $t$ for which $$t\cap S = \emptyset.$$

It can be shown that this implies that there is no set $S$ for which $S\in S$, and more generally there is no infinite descending chain $$\dots\in S_3 \in S_2\in S_1.$$

The regularity axiom, though, is not what prevents Russell's paradox from arising in ZF.  The paradox arises from the idea of a universal set, not from irregularity.  Regularity just tells us that $S\notin S$ for all $S$. So if Russell's set $R$ were to exist, it would simply contain all sets—it would be a universal set.  But Cantor's paradox shows there can't be any such thing.

#### Restricted comprehension

Instead, what fixes Russell's paradox in ZF is called *restricted comprehension*.  In  ZF you are not allowed to perform [unrestricted comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension), which means you may not construct the set of all $x$ having property $\Psi$, which would be written $$\{x\mid \Psi(x)\}.\tag1$$ Rather, you are only allowed to construct the *subset* of some other set  $S$ that consists of the elements of $S$ that have  property $\Psi$:  $$\{x\in S\mid \Psi(x)\}\tag2$$ where $S$ is some set. This is called “restricted comprehension” because the construction is *restricted* to the elements of $S$.

(Note that if there is a universal set $V$, then restricting comprehension accomplishes nothing because  $\{x\in V\mid \Psi(x)\}$ is exactly unrestricted comprehension.)

We can still try to proceed with the  Russell argument in ZF. Suppose $S$ is some set that we have already. We may construct $$R(S) =\{x\in S\mid x\notin x\},$$ the set of all elements of $S$ for which $x\notin x$ is true.  But because the axiom of regularity allows us to prove $x\notin x$ for all $x$,  we simply get $$R(S)=S$$ for all $S$.

### Morse-Kelley

[Morse-Kelley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory) (MK) set theory allows unrestricted comprehension like $(1)$, but interprets it differently.  MK distinguishes between “sets” and “classes”.  Any property $\Psi$ defines a class, but not every class is a set.  The notation $\{x \mid \Psi(x)\}$ is understood to mean “the class of all *sets* with property $\Psi$”.

In MK set theory, we can construct $R = \{x \mid x\notin x\}$ but it means the class of all *sets* that satisfy $x\notin x$.  Russell's argument simply shows that $R$ is not itself a set, and so that $R\notin R$.  Morse-Kelley theory does have a universal *class* $V$ of all sets but instead of leading to a paradox the Cantor-Russell argument merely shows that $V$ is not a set.

#### NBG

[von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel  set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) (NBG) is very similar to MK.  There are “good” sets and “bad” sets, and only “good” sets are allowed to be members of other sets.  For a bad set $b$, $b\in x$ is always false.  Russell's $R$ then becomes the set of all *good* sets that satisfy $x\notin x$, and Russell's argument simply shows that $R$ is a bad set.

### Russell's theory of types

Russell himself developed a theory that tried to solve the problem, called the [*theory of types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica#Ramified_types_and_the_axiom_of_reducibility).  In this theory sets belong to different *types*, and a set may only contain elements whose types are all the same.  Then, at a particular type we can construct $R=\{x\mid x\notin x\}$ but it is only the set of all things of a certain type that  satisfy $x\notin x$.  Here, Russell's argument just shows that $R$ has some *other* type, and again $R\notin R$.

Russell's theory does have universal sets, but for each type $T$ there is a different universal set $V_T$ that contains everything of type $T$. The paradoxical argument only shows that $V_T$ is not a thing of type $T$.

Russell's theory had some technical problems which led to it falling out of use.  Most simply, there are many different empty sets, one for each type.

### NF and related systems

Quine's [New Foundations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations) (NF) and systems based on it are an attempt to rehabilitate the “type” idea behind Russell's theory.  The types themselves are abandoned, and the language replaces  unlimited comprehension $(1)$ with *stratified comprehension*.  This says that you can construct a set $\{x\mid \Psi(x)\}$ only when $\Psi$ is a “stratified” formula. A formula $\Psi$ is stratified if  one  can associate each variables in $\Psi$ with a number, and the numbers have to match up in a particular way: if $\Psi$ contains the subformula “$x\in y$” then the number associated with $x$ must be one less than the number associated with $y$.  In particular, this means that   $x\in x$ and $x\notin x$ are not stratified, and cannot appear in the $\Psi$ that used used in a  comprehension.

### Others

Most set theories adopt some sort of the hierarchy you suggested, and eliminate  any set $x$ for which $x\in x$.  Peter Aczel developed a [“non-wellfounded” set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory) that was intended to permit sets for which $x\in x$ is true, and similarly sets $x$ and $y$ where both $x\in y$ and $y\in x$.  I don't remember how Aczel deals with Russell's paradox.   It may be that it doesn't come up because there is still no universal set.

Finally, [Randall Holmes](https://randall-holmes.github.io/Bibliography/setbiblio.html) has done work on set theories that *do* have a universal set $V$ and that get around Cantor's paradox in different ways.

Comment: I have corrected a great many errors that I made in my first drafts of this. It would be foolish to think that I had corrected them all. If you spot an error, please let me know, or just correct it yourself.